# Add Labels to D3.JS Decision Tree Path

Tags: d3.js

I have this collapsible decision tree in d3js: https://observablehq.com/@adamw005/collapsible-tree
and I want to add labels to the paths. I want it to be the `count` value in the JSON for the current node divided by previous node (so it shows the percent of time each path is taken).

I have found this code to find the center of the path, but other than that I'm not sure how to do this

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return path.centroid(d)[0];
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return path.centroid(d)[1];
})
```

Comment: Link to Observable doesn't work ("Sorry, we couldn’t find that page.")

Comment: @TomShanley updated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Tidy Tree fork with the link labels:
https://observablehq.com/d/da472aa24f6e178e

To change the label's text, put the string value in the 'text' attribute:
link.append("text")
    .text("my label text")

Comment: The link is broken - I think you have to hit 'Publish' on the top right

Comment: @Adam12344 you're right. Here is the link: https://observablehq.com/@mrovinsky/tidy-tree